# Click NavItem to show a Popup/Modal in React/Materilize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

Am new in React and am trying to make a **NavItem** clickable to show a **Popup** which is known as the Modal in materialize. 
I read about the materialize documentation but it doesn't seem to work, below is the link to :

[NavBar](https://react-materialize.github.io/#/navbar)

[Modals](https://react-materialize.github.io/#/modals)

This is the code am currently having :

```
    class NavBar extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar  className='white' brand={brandColor} right>
                    <NavItem className='text-navbar' > Sign Up</NavItem>
                    <NavItem onClick={() => <Modal/>}>Getting started</NavItem>

                </Navbar>

                <Modal
                    className={"modal"}
                    header='Modal Header'
                    fixedFooter
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                    labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
                    nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
                    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
                    culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                </Modal>



           </div>
        );
    }
}

export default NavBar;
```

Am looking for a way to embed the Modal on to the NavItem. what steps should I take?

Comment: Where is your modal though?

Comment: Its there now @Timggwp

Comment: I did not use react so just will be guessing from codes given in sources that you provided. I think you missed `trigger`. Add `trigger={<NavItem>Getting started</NavItem>}>` to your modal.

Comment: @Timggwp, it still not clear to me

Comment: Try the one in the answer

Answer (score 0):

So there are several ways to do it. This one is without trigger. Your forgot to give and `Id` to the modal and call it from `nav item`

```
<Navbar  className='white' brand={brandColor} right>
    <NavItem className='text-navbar' > Sign Up</NavItem>
    <NavItem 
        onClick={() => {
            $('#myModal').modal('open')
        }}>
        Getting started
   </NavItem>
</Navbar>

<Modal
      id="myModal"
      className={"modal"}
      header='Modal Header'
      fixedFooter>

      Text goes here
</Modal>
```

Comment: Am getting `'$' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: When i remove `$` , the page loads , but when i click the NavItem nothing comes.

Comment: You need to give a link to jQuery. Seems like it works with jQuery.